# CalculateColumn: Result column should contain filtered table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, schematiq

- I am using **Schematiq 3.0**
- I have a table with timestamps in a column.
- For each row, I would now like to calculate a table, which is the
  original table filtered by the timestamp plus and minus some offset.
- I have already calculated the minimum and maximum boundaries of the
  timestamp in separate columns, but I struggle with handing over the
  table itself as an input.

As an easier example, I am below just trying to add the table itself into every row of the result table. Once that can be accomplished, I guess the filtering should be easy.

I have tried the following:

- Cell B16 contains the table which has the columns TimeStamp,
  MinTimeStamp (and others).
- Cell C17 contains the function:

  ```
  ="l => "&B16&""
  ```
- Cell B17 contains the formula:

  ```
  =tbl.CalculateColumn(B16,,C17,"Result")
  ```

The error message I get is

> Error:error in function tbl.CalculateColumn ('function' argument 
>   to 'tbl.CalculateColumn' must be of type 'function')caused by:error in
>   unnamed or inner function. Unexpected character(s) found: 
>   l => ♦‌table(52)

Can you please suggest if and how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to incorporate another object into a snippet, then you can only put it into the snippet if it makes sense as text. If you want to import the value of a table, then you can use `fn.FixInput()` to do this:

`=fn.FixInput("x => x", B16)`

This creates a function with one input that just returns the input value, then it "fixes" the value of the input to be whatever is in `B16`. This means that you now have a function with no inputs, which will return the object from `B16`.

Hope this is what you need!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. What I did now is to calculate a column with the fixed table function as a result, giving me the full table in each row. Then I use a Template function to filter on each row for that row's particular criteria.
Just out of interest, is it also possible to get that accomplished without having to add the full table to each row first, i.e. add the filtered tables on the fly in a template function?

Comment: Can you try the snippet `T => tbl.Filter(T, "A", 'x => AND(x > 10, x < 20)')`. If you try using `fn.FixInput` on this again, and pass in to your `tbl.CalculateColumn` function, then the result in each row of the calculated table will be your original table filtered where column "A" is between 10 and 20.

Comment: If you get this working, then you can also pass in additional parameters of two more columns in to your snippet function: `(T, low, upp) => tbl.Filter(T, "B", 'x=> AND(x>'& low & ', x <' & upp & ')')`. (The "&" symbol here means concatenate the string expression with the actual value of "low" and "upp")

Comment: I am not sure if I got you answer correctly, but I have finally found a solution. I am defining a table as an input to my template and use 'fn.FixInput' on the template function before calling it. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Jon G's comment for your simpler example, in cell B16 you have your table, and in cell B17 you can do:

```
=fn.FixInput("tbl => tbl", B16)
```

which is now a function depending on no parameters (that will always return the table in B16). Now in cell C17 you can write:

```
=tbl.CalculateColumn(B16,,C17,"Result")
```

Since C17 is a formula with no parameters, this will always return you the table from B16 in each row of the calculated table.

Comment: Thanks, that helped togeter with Jon G's answer.